# Showing command line output on a html page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, bash

I am building a web app which runs certain commands on the terminal and display the results back on web app. I am able to run commands using child_process.exec and fetch the results the problem i'm facing is while displaying it on an html page.

I want something like this: 
[image]

Is there any way to show the command line output like this ? Any leads would do. Thank you.

Comment: what format are you getting the results in?

Comment: @YaakovAinspan plain text filled with \r\n.

Comment: So... what have you tried? Do you have any code showing your problem?

Comment: I am appending it to a text node and displaying the result but the formatting is not even remotely close to how it looks on terminal. [link]https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9s5q.png

Comment: Can you post some sample output so I can see what it looks like?

Comment: Your file is encoded under windows. Encode your output file with unix line ending .

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For a terminal/shell/console-like experience in a browser or web app, check out...

**JS solutions, for interactivity**

- https://xtermjs.org
- https://github.com/chjj/tty.js
- http://sdether.github.io/josh.js
- https://terminal.jcubic.pl/
- https://github.com/liftoff/GateOne
- https://github.com/1j01/simple-console
- https://www.masswerk.at/termlib/index.html

**HTML/CSS-only solutions, for non-interactivity**

To simulate a terminal, with no connectivity or interactivity:

- https://github.com/ines/termynal
- https://github.com/tj/node-term-css
- https://guides.codechewing.com/mac-terminal-shell-css-html

Or perhaps start from scratch with a black background, white mono-space font and build it up from there...

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/MarsAndBack/pen/oJBXpN)

```css
#container {
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  max-height: 400px;
  padding: 3em;
}

#content {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <p>Hello world</p>
    <p>Hello world</p>
    <p>Hello world</p>
    <p>Hello world</p>
  </div>
</div>
```