# Display terminal output live onto webpage

Tags: javascript, python, html, node.js, xtermjs

I'm trying to create a web page where the user will press a button, and it will send some code presented in a div to the terminal which will be executed, I would then want the live output of that code to be displayed in a terminal like window on my page.

I have looked at some ways to do this but haven't really found anything that allows this type of use case.

I saw a way a terminal can be displayed on a webpage as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53860093/showing-command-line-output-on-a-html-page) using xterm.js but there doesn't seem to be much documentation as to how to link this with an actual terminal to display live output. However, I'd assume it is done via some form of web sockets to capture the output.

I have also seen ways on how to send commands to a terminal using child_process.exec in node.js but I'm struggling to find anything to link the two together.

I don't want the users to be able to interact or run code from the terminal window on the page I would just like it to show the output of the code when they press the button.

Does anyone know of any technologies that could facilitate this kind of use case? Possibly something in Python but my webpage currently uses html and javascript. I understand this won't be possible with just client side code and I will need a server side langauge but preferably something that intergrates with javascript nicely.

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/tsl0922/ttyd ?

Comment: I'm more looking for something like, for example, if the button that was clicked sent the "ls" command to the bash terminal, the terminal window on the webpage would show the live output of the "ls" command but the terminal window on the webpage isn't interactive and is only there to show output and not allow the user to run any commands from it

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I have managed to create my own solution to this with a mixture of JavaScript, Bash and PHP. I also created my own terminal window design to display the returned response.

Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: mind sharing what plan you came up with?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question, it just states that you have one, with insufficient details to reproduce it.

Comment: Better to tell what you did next time

Comment: I ended up completing this by designing a standard terminal window design using CSS/HTML which would house the output I wanted. The user would be able to click a button to run the requested command and client-side Javascript would send the requested command to the server which would be processed by PHP and execute the command on the server as a bash command. The PHP code would then capture the output of the command and save it in a file which I would then send back using PHP as a response from the server to the client which would be capture the response and output in the terminal window.

Comment: Possibly not the most efficient way of doing it but with the time I had it worked exactly how I wanted it to and didn't take too long to get a response back :

Answer (score 1):

It's a complex set of requirements, building a terminal. Not to say you shouldn't try, as you'd learn a lot in the process - but for an out of the box solution, consider looking at [xterm.js](https://xtermjs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const btnTo = document.querySelector('#btnTo');
const btnFrom = document.querySelector('#btnFrom');
const term = document.querySelector('#term');

btnTo.addEventListener('click', grab, false);
btnFrom.addEventListener('click', update, false);
function grab (){
  const test = document.querySelector('.test');
  term.textContent =  test.outerHTML;
}
function update (){
  const test = document.querySelector('.test');
  test.outerHTML = term.textContent;
}
```

```css
button {
 display: inline;
}
.test{
 font-size: .9rem;
}
.terminal {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  height: 40vh;
  width: 95%;
}
```

```html
<div class=test>
  <p>Hello World! You can edit it in terminal and even use sockets for backend editing</p>
</div>
<button id="btnTo">to terminal</button>
<button id="btnFrom">from terminal</button>
<pre id="term" class="terminal" contenteditable></pre>
```

Did you mean something like that?

Comment: Sort of. Essentally what I'm looking for is when the user clicks the button, and for example it sends the "ls" command, the command will be sent to a backend terminal on a ubuntu server, I would then want the output of that "ls" command that was sent to the terminal on the remote server, to then be output live onto a non interative terminal window on the webpage for the user to see? If that makes sense?

Comment: I see now. You need to write a back-end, run a command on the back-end through the process and return the output  to the client.

Comment: Yes that's right, I just can't seem to find any solutions that can combine the two :/